# UI Elements only update when focus is moved away from original button/input

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, razor-pages, blazor-webassembly

I am having an issue where I would press a button and a response would be given from the server but the UI would not update to display the response I have set for it until I start interacting with something else. Can't seem to figure out what is causing this. Been going through the code, making changes in terms of the UI layout but nothing seemed to work. I have a gif here to better demonstrate. I have tried using `StateHasChanged` but this did not seem to work either

[image]

### Razor page

```
<EditForm Model="@AssignUser" OnValidSubmit="@AddUserToProject">

@*    <DataAnnotationsValidator />*@
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="custom-control-label"> Assign Users </label>
    <InputText placeholder="Username" id="inlineFormInputGroup" type="email" @bind-Value="@AssignUser.UserName" class="form-control" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</div>
</EditForm>
//display messages depending on outcome
@if (userNotFoundError == true)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        User could not be found
    </div>
}

@if (userExistsAlready == true)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        User is already on the project
    </div>
}
```

### Add user to project function

```
private bool userNotFoundError = false;
private bool userExistsAlready = false;
private async void AddUserToProject()
{
    try
    {
        var response = await Http.PutAsJsonAsync($"Projects/add/User/{AssignUser.UserName}/{projectItem.ProjectId}", AssignUser);

        // Attempt add adding someone who is already on the project?
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
        {
            StateHasChanged();

            if (userNotFoundError == true)
            {
                userNotFoundError = false;
            }
            userExistsAlready = true;

            
        }
// Attempt at adding someone who does not exist as a user?
        else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
        {
            StateHasChanged();

            if (userExistsAlready == true)
            {
                userExistsAlready = false;
            }
            userNotFoundError = true;
        }
        else
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var userobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApplicationUser>(content);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Navigation.NavigateTo("/projects");
            userNotFoundError = false;
            userExistsAlready = false;
            StateHasChanged();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        userNotFoundError = true;
    }
}
```

### Add user function in controller

```
[HttpPut("add/User/{userName}/{projID}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUserToProject(string userName, Guid projID)
{

    var project = _context.Projects.Include(u => u.AssignedUsersToProject).FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProjectId.ToString().Equals(projID.ToString()));

    try
    {
        var user = _context.Users.First(u => u.UserName.Equals(userName));

        if (!project.AssignedUsersToProject.Any(u => u.UserName.Equals(user.UserName))) { 
            project.AssignedUsersToProject.Add(user);                    
        } else
        {
            return Forbid();
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    try
    {
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ProjectExists(projID))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: The question is almost complete but we can't see where/how you show the error. That might matter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the post to show this.

Comment: The error code looks ok - it must have been just the async void then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
private async void AddUserToProject()
```

to

```
private async Task AddUserToProject()
```

and it should work.

You can then also remove all those `StateHasChanged()` calls, they serve no purpose anymore.

Blazor does not know when an `async void` is completed. When you use an `async Task` method then Blazor will automatically rerender your UI when the method is finished.

But I do suspect there is another problem with showing the error. The StateHasChanged() calls should have 'repaired' the `async void` for most branches.

Comment: There is a simple rule: ___avoid async void___.  Will save you a lot of problems.